# How to set map to only hold one marker at a time, with two separate functions creating markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, progressive-web-apps

I am writing this question, having previously searched quite a lot for this question, but haven't found a thread that I can use for my current problem. (Probably due to lack of skill). If there is a question that addresses exactly this, please redirect me to it!

I am creating a PWA that uses google maps for user interaction, the idea being that a user can place a marker on said map by either:

1. Clicking the map on the desired location
2. Clicking a button that places a marker on the user's current location
3. Writing the address (geocoding)

For now, I have a code that permits me doing the first two actions. In both functions, I have an IF, that tries to overwrite any existing markers, so as to only have a maximum of one marker on the map. (Ignore geocoding remark, it hasn't been implemented yet)

I come across the following problem:
Whilst if the user clicks the map, and then clicks the geolocating button, the first marker is removed. (Desired outcome)

- If the user clicks the geolocating button, and then clicks the map, no marker is removed.

I can't get a working HTML/CSS/Javascript snippet to work, as it requires hiding the google maps key, and that exceeds my capabilities.
But I think that the problem(s) lie in my Javascript code:

```
var map2;
var marker2;
function initialize2() {

    google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';
    var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom:19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "greedy",

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.727751, 1.827424),
        restriction: {
            latLngBounds: {
              north: 41.753,
              south: 41.715,
              east: 1.857,
              west: 1.806,
            },
          },
        
        styles: [{ // VISIBLE BARS RESTAURANTS
            featureType: "poi",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }, {
            featureType: "poi.park",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }],
        }, {
            featureType: "poi.park",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }, {
            featureType: "transit",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }]
    };
    
    
    
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-inseg'), mapOptions2);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessGeolocating);
        
    }
 

// Add marker when map is clicked (and overwrite when it is clicked again)
   

    google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    function placeMarker(location) {

        if (marker2 == null)
            {
                marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map2
                }); 
            } 
        else
            {
                marker2.setPosition(location); 
            } 

    }

    
    
    
    function onSuccessGeolocating(position) {

        var circleBigOpt = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude), 
            map: map2,
            radius: position.coords.accuracy,
            fillColor:"#4285f4",
            fillOpacity:0.1,
            strokeWeight:0
        };
    
        var circleBig = new google.maps.Circle(circleBigOpt);
    
    
            
    
        var positionMarkerOptions = {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude),
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 10,
                fillColor: '#4285f4',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '#ffffff',
                strokeWeight: 1
            },
            map: map2
            };
    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(positionMarkerOptions);

        map2.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude));
    
        // Function that adds marker on the user's current location, when button "boto-marcarMapa" is clicked
        

    
        document.getElementById("boto-marcarMapa").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
            
           if (marker2 == null) 
            { 
                marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude),
                map: map2
            });
            }
            else 
            {
                //marker2.setPosition(position);
                marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude),
                    map: map2
                });
            }

            //marker2.setMap(null);
            
        });
    
    }





}
window.addEventListener('load', initialize2);
```

Clarification: **marker2** is the interactive marker that users create through the 3 actions stated. **marker** is just a blue dot that appears automatically on user's current location if the function **onSuccessGeolocating** gets approved.

I know there are a lot of google.maps.Marker related questions, and I have really tried resolving this on my own (setting marker2 as global variable, trying to set map's markers to null before the functions..) but have gotten nowhere.

Thank you very much, and sorry for possibly confusing code lines.

Comment: You can't reuse the same variable for two instances if you expect to handle the two instances differently. You need a second variable, e.g. marker3 (or better named freeCameraMarker instead of marker2 and userLocationMarker instead of marker3).

Comment: I see, Then, how could I make the two different variables codependant? I originally had different variable names, but tried to unify them so they would recognise one another. Thanks

Comment: Your question also contradicts itself: "_only have a maximum of one marker on the map_" ... "_problem: If the user clicks the map, and then clicks the geolocating button, the first marker is removed._"; can you clarify which it should be? Should there be a maximum of 2 markers or 1, and if 1, what's the problem? I'm trying to understand how to answer the question but as it stands right now, I think the question is too unfocused.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I just edited it. The desired outcome is that only one "marker2" remains on the map. 
The problem, as I understand it, is that that the marker created by the geolocating button (userLocationMarker in your terms) doesn't recognise the existance of the freeCameraMarker, and just creates another.

Comment: Why don't you simply keep the same reference for both markers and the same logic? ie. If marker already exists, reposition, if it doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: That's what I tried to accomplish with the IFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you create new markers, but you don't reference back to it in `placeMarker` when you want to replace the position later on.

```js
var map2;
var marker2;

function initialize2() {

    google.maps.controlStyle = 'azteca';
    var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom:19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "greedy",

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.727751, 1.827424),
        restriction: {
            latLngBounds: {
              north: 41.753,
              south: 41.715,
              east: 1.857,
              west: 1.806,
            },
          },
        
        styles: [{ // VISIBLE BARS RESTAURANTS
            featureType: "poi",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }, {
            featureType: "poi.park",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }],
        }, {
            featureType: "poi.park",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }, {
            featureType: "transit",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }]
    };
    
    
    
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-inseg'), mapOptions2);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessGeolocating);
    }
 

// Add marker when map is clicked (and overwrite when it is clicked again)
   

    google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    function placeMarker(location) {
        if (marker2 == null)
        {
            marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map2
            }); 
        } 
        else
        {
            marker2.setPosition(location); 
        } 
    }

    
    
    
    function onSuccessGeolocating(position) {

        var circleBigOpt = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude), 
            map: map2,
            radius: position.coords.accuracy,
            fillColor:"#4285f4",
            fillOpacity:0.1,
            strokeWeight:0
        };
    
        var circleBig = new google.maps.Circle(circleBigOpt);

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 10,
                fillColor: '#4285f4',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '#ffffff',
                strokeWeight: 1
            },
            map: map2
        });

        map2.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude));
    
        // Function that adds marker on the user's current location, when button "boto-marcarMapa" is clicked
        

    
        document.getElementById("boto-marcarMapa").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
            
            placeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude));


            //marker2.setMap(null);
            
        });
    
    }





}
window.addEventListener('load', initialize2);
```

Side-note: in the URL in your `<script>` tag, you should have a `callback` search parameter (usually `callback=oninit`), Google's script will call this through `window.oninit` when it's been loaded, so I'd replace your window event listener with:

```js
window.oninit = initialize2;
```

Comment: My first sentence contradicts my first comment to your question, but that's because your question has been clarified. :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the helpful side-note. Your code does remove the current location marker, if the user first clicks the button and then a random location in the map, but if the button is hit a second time, the freeCameraMarker is not removed from the map (same outcome shown on the question's screenshot).  So.. it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @enricw I've updated my answer, I missed the last section.

Comment: Excellent, that does the trick. My only residual problem (that is probably due to non clarity of my question) is that the blue circle that marks the user's location now dissapears when a marker is set (the problem being that the circle should always stay put).

Comment: @enricw I misinterpreted the usage of that circle then! I've reverted those changes.

Comment: Great. I modified the 'new.google.maps.Marker' line to create a variable and then a marker with the specified options, because the current code doesn't put the blue circle on the map. But everything else works a charm, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

The issue is that you create a new variable (marker) that holds the newly created marker, but you don't reference back to it in placeMarker when you want to replace the position later on.

I've changed your placeMarker function to take a type argument which is null or "circle" to be able to change the marker2 instance options without redundant code. There's a lot of code that needs improvement but this will achieve your desired outcome.